# Dose X converges in probability to Y converges in probability to a constant z implies X converges in probability to z

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have $\frac{1}{n}\sum_j^n X_{ij}$ converges in probability to $Y_i$ and  $\frac{1}{n}\sum_y^n Y_{j}$ converges in probability to a constant $z$, where $Y_i$ is not the expectation value of $X_{ij}$ but $z$ is the the expectation value of $Y_i$.

How to prove rigously $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n\frac{1}{n}\sum_j^n X_{ij}$ converges in probability to $z$? Many thanks!!!

==================================================================
I have tried to prove in the following way, but feel there are some places loose and not accurate in it.

I wrote  $j=1,,,n_0$ and $i=1,...,n_1$ for convenience (I am not sure if I can do this)

Since $\frac{1}{n_0}\sum_j^{n_0} X_{ij}$  converges in probability to $Y_i$: given $\varepsilon_0>0$, $\delta_0>0$ and $n_1$  there exists an $m_0(\varepsilon_0, \varepsilon_0, n_1)$ such that, for all $n_0>m_0(\varepsilon_0, \delta_0, n_1)$
\begin{equation}
 P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n_0}\sum_j^{n_0} X_{ij}-Y_i\right|>\varepsilon_0\right)<\frac{\delta_0}{n_1}
\end{equation}

Therefore
\begin{align*}
P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_i^{n_1}\left(\frac{1}{n_0}\sum_j^{n_0} X_{ij}-Y_{i}\right)\right|>\varepsilon_0\right)&=P\left(\left|\sum_i^{n_1}\left(\frac{1}{n_0}\sum_j^{n_0}X_{ij}-Y_i\right)\right|>n_1\varepsilon_0\right)\\
&\leq P\left(\sum_i^{n_1}\left|\left(\frac{1}{n_0}\sum_j^{n_0}X_{ij}-Y_i\right)\right|>n_1\varepsilon_0\right)\\
&\leq \sum_i^{n_1} P\left(\left|\left(\frac{1}{n_0}\sum_j^{n_0}X_{ij}-Y_i\right)\right|>\varepsilon_0\right)\\
&<\delta_0
\end{align*}

Since $\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_i^{n_1}Y_i \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} z$: given $\varepsilon_1>0$ and $\delta_1>0$ there exists an $m_1(\varepsilon_1, \delta_1)$ such that, for all $n_1>m_1(\varepsilon_0, \delta_1)$
\begin{equation}
 P\left(\left|\left(\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_i^{n_1}Y_i\right)-z\right|>\varepsilon_1\right)<\delta_1.
\end{equation}

It follows
\begin{align*}
\delta_0+\delta_1&>P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_i^{n_1}\left(\frac{1}{n_0}\sum_j^{n_0}X_{ij}-Y_i\right)\right|>\varepsilon_0\right)+P\left(\left|\left(\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_i^{n_1}Y_i\right)-z\right|>\varepsilon_1\right)\\
&\geq P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_i^{n_1}\left(\frac{1}{n_0}\sum_j^{n_0}X_{ij}-Y_i\right)\right|+\left|\left(\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_i^{n_1}Y_i\right)-z\right|>  \varepsilon_0+\varepsilon_1  \right)\\
&\geq P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_i^{n_1}\frac{1}{n_0}\sum_j^{n_0}X_{ij}-z\right|>  \varepsilon_0+\varepsilon_1  \right).
\end{align*}

Therefore, given $\delta=\delta_0+\delta_1$ and $ \varepsilon= \varepsilon_0+\varepsilon_1$,  for all $n_1>m_1(\varepsilon_1, \delta_1)$ and $n_0>m_0(\varepsilon_0, \delta_0, n_1)$
\begin{equation}
 P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_i^{n_1}\frac{1}{n_0}\sum_j^{n_0}X_{ij}-z\right|>  \varepsilon  \right)<\delta.
\end{equation}
Does this prove $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n\frac{1}{n}\sum_j^n X_{ij}$ converges in probability to $z$ as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

The result fails in general, here is a deterministic counterexample. Let $x_{ij}=0$ if $j\lt2i$, $x_{ij}=j$ if $j=2i$ and $x_{ij}=1$ if $j\gt2i$.

Then $\frac1n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_{ij}=\mathbf 1_{n\geqslant2i}$ hence $y_i=1$ for every $i$ and $\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_i\to1$ while $\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_{ij}\to\frac12$.